# Внесение изменений в редактор групповой политике на C#

Tags: c#, windows

Нужен код, который позволяет редактировать групповую политику (gpedit.msc) на языке программирования C#.

Пример исполнения - программа Win 10 Tweaker, как я понял, некоторые твики использую gpedit.msc, программа написана на языке C#. Возможно ли это вообще? Если да, то как? Может есть документация? Сам я не нашёл.

Comment: Работа с реестром Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316511/5045688